# Possible to hook up 3x 12V, .5A cooling fans to a single 12V, 2A power supply?

Tags: power-supply, fan, cooling

If I have an adaptor with a power supply of 12V, 2A., will I be able to or will it even be safe to hook up three (3) computer cooling fans (on to the same adaptor) with this rating: DC 12V,0.5A? For any question on why am I asking this, well, it's basically just to save on the number of power points I'd need to plug in three basic cooling fans for an indoor hydroponic system. I'd really appreciate anyone's help on this. Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The voltage is the same.

0.5A × 3 = 1.5A.

That's less than power supply's capabilities, so you should be good.